# Nested object stored as state variable deleting newer values when older values are modified

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which passes user input value to a props function. The parent function just appends those inputs to an object. However, when an older value is modified, all the newer values are removed. Please refer to the screenshots.

This is the parent. ExamArea.js

```
import McqQuestion from './McqQuestion'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './ExamArea.css'

function ExamArea(props) {

    const[currentQuesID, setCurrentQuesID] = useState(2);
    const[mcqQuestionList, setmcqQuestionList] = useState([<McqQuestion returnfunc={returnFromMcqQuestion} id={1}/>]);
    const[ques, setQues] = useState({});


    function returnFromMcqQuestion(quesID, thisQuestion) {
        var temp = {...ques};
        temp["ques"+quesID] = thisQuestion;
        console.log(temp);

        setQues(temp);
      }

    function generateMCQ(questionid) {
        return (<McqQuestion returnfunc={returnFromMcqQuestion} id={questionid}/>)
    }


    function addAnotherQuestion() {
        setmcqQuestionList(mcqQuestionList.concat(generateMCQ(currentQuesID)));
        setCurrentQuesID(currentQuesID+1);
     }
        

    return (

        <div className="ExamArea">
            {mcqQuestionList}
            <button onClick={()=>addAnotherQuestion()} class="add_another_question_button">+ Add Another Question</button>
        </div> 

        );
    

}

export default ExamArea;
```

This is the child.

```
import './McqQuestion.css'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Paper, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';

/*
This is the component that lets the maker create the question, and then stores the question to packedQuestion.
packedQuestipn is in a format which can be directly sent to the API to be uploaded to the database.
A basic question has question_text, question.title

Props passed:
props.id = The Question ID.
props.returnfunc = The function that gets called with packedQuestion and props.id when everything is done. 
                    props.returnfunc(props.id, packedQuestion) is the thing that is called.

*/


function McqQuestion(props) {

    
    const [packedQuestion, setPackedQuestion] = useState({});
    useEffect(()=> props.returnfunc(props.id, packedQuestion));


    /*These two variables store a local copy of packedQuestion. These variables are first updated with the information from
    onChange (or a variation of it), and then packedQuestion is set to an instance of this. */

    let local_question_mcq = {};
    let local_answerChoices_mcq =  {};

    function fillUpQuestionWithDefault(){

        function addOption(character, value) {
            local_answerChoices_mcq[character] = value;
            local_question_mcq["answer_choices"] = local_answerChoices_mcq;
        }

        function addQuestion(title, value){

            if(title){
                local_question_mcq['title'] = value;
            }
            else {
                local_question_mcq['question_text'] = value;
            }

        }

        addQuestion(true, "Question "+props.id);
        addQuestion(false, "");

        addOption("a", "");
        addOption("b", "");
        addOption("c", "");
        addOption("d", "");

        local_question_mcq['title'] = "Question " + props.id;
        local_question_mcq['id'] = props.id;
        
        setPackedQuestion(local_question_mcq);

    }

    useEffect(() =>fillUpQuestionWithDefault(), []);


    function optionOnInputFunc(character, value) {
        local_question_mcq = {...packedQuestion};
        local_answerChoices_mcq = {...local_question_mcq["answer_choices"]};
        local_answerChoices_mcq[character] = value;
        local_question_mcq["answer_choices"] = local_answerChoices_mcq;
        
        setPackedQuestion(local_question_mcq);

    }

    function questionOnInputFunc(title, value) {

        if(title){
            local_question_mcq = {...packedQuestion};
            local_question_mcq['title'] = value;
            setPackedQuestion(local_question_mcq);
        }

        else {
            local_question_mcq = {...packedQuestion};
            local_question_mcq['question_text'] = value;
            setPackedQuestion(local_question_mcq);
        }
        
    }


    function mcqChoiceGeneratingFunc() {

        return (
            
            <div class = "Opt">
                <TextField onChange = {e => optionOnInputFunc('a', e.target.value)}  label="Option A" variant="filled" multiline rowsMax={4}/>
                <TextField onChange = {e => optionOnInputFunc('b', e.target.value)}  label="Option B" variant="filled" multiline rowsMax={4}/>
                <TextField onChange = {e => optionOnInputFunc('c', e.target.value)}  label="Option C" variant="filled" multiline rowsMax={4}/>
                <TextField onChange = {e => optionOnInputFunc('d', e.target.value)}  label="Option D" variant="filled" multiline rowsMax={4}/>
            </div>

        );
    }



    return (

        <Paper class="Question">
            <form class="Question-form">

                <a class = "editpencil">✎</a>
                <InputBase class = "questionedit"
                    onChange = {e => questionOnInputFunc(true, e.target.value)}
                    defaultValue={"Question "+props.id}
                    inputProps = {{"maxlength": 40}}/>
                

                <div class="question-text">
                    <TextField onChange = {e => questionOnInputFunc(false, e.target.value)} variant="outlined" fullWidth="true" label="Type your question"></TextField>
                </div>
                {mcqChoiceGeneratingFunc()}


            </form>
            
        </Paper>


    );

}

export default McqQuestion;
```

The behavior I am describing can be seen in these screenshots.

The first two screenshots are expected. Two new questions were added and their respective objects were in the console log.

[Expected Behavior at the start of the state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJUKi.png)

[Expected behavior when two new questions were added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7f1X.png)

[When question 1 was edited while questions 2 and 3 were there, the objects for question 3 disappeared.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N1cI.png)

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: I think the instance of the returnFromMcqQuestion function that is being passed is an older version of that function. I am unfamiliar with Javascript and how it handles references to functions. Is that a thing?

Comment: can you upload your code to codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

### ExamArea

1. Storing react components in state is a React anti-pattern and sure-fire way to get yourself some stale state enclosures.

Store *just* the data in state and render the UI *from* it.

2. Any time you are updating react state that ***depends*** on the previous state (i.e. appending an element to an array, incrementing a count/id, etc...) you don't use a functional state update.

Use a functional state update to correctly update from any previous state versus state from the previous render cycle.

### McqQuestion

1. Once I resolved your issues in `ExamArea` I was a bit thrown off by the usage of `local_question_mcq` and `local_answerChoices_mcq`. At first glance they appeared to be "state" that wasn't part of component state.

Limit the scope of utility variables such as `local_question_mcq` and `local_answerChoices_mcq`

2. Similar issues with the functional updates, but coupled to the overscoped `local_question_mcq` and `local_answerChoices_mcq`.

Use a functional state update to directly update `packedQuestion` in the `onChange` handlers.

## Solution

#### ExamArea

1. Store ***only data*** in component state.
2. Map state to UI in `render` function.
3. Use functional state update to map previous state to next state. Use the question ID to match the question that needs to be updated and *also* shallow copy ***it***.
4. Pass `returnFromMcqQuestion` as prop directly (*not stored in state either*).

Code:

```
function ExamArea(props) {
  const [currentQuesID, setCurrentQuesID] = useState(2);
  const [mcqQuestionList, setmcqQuestionList] = useState([{ id: 1 }]); // <-- store data only

  function returnFromMcqQuestion(quesID, thisQuestion) {
    setmcqQuestionList((mcqQuestionList) => // <-- functional state update
      mcqQuestionList.map((question) =>
        question.id === quesID // <-- shallow copy matching question
          ? {
              ...question,
              ...thisQuestion
            }
          : question
      )
    );
  }

  function generateMCQ(questionid) {
    return {
      id: questionid
    };
  }

  function addAnotherQuestion() {
    setmcqQuestionList((mcqQuestionList) => // <-- functional state update
      mcqQuestionList.concat(generateMCQ(currentQuesID))
    );
    setCurrentQuesID((c) => c + 1); // <-- functional state update
  }

  return (
    <div className="ExamArea">
      {mcqQuestionList.map(({ id }) => (
        <McqQuestion
          key={id}
          returnfunc={returnFromMcqQuestion} // <-- pass callback directly
          id={id}
        />
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={addAnotherQuestion}
        className="add_another_question_button"
      >
        + Add Another Question
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### McqQuestion

1. Use functional state update to map previous state to next state.
2. Limit the scope of `local_question_mcq` and `local_answerChoices_mcq`, move them *into* `fillUpQuestionWithDefault` and declare them `const`.
3. Make code more **DRY** where possible.
4. Fix `class` vs `className` and other various React warnings.

Code:

```
function McqQuestion(props) {
  const [packedQuestion, setPackedQuestion] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    props.returnfunc(props.id, packedQuestion); // <-- update state in parent
  }, [packedQuestion]);

  function fillUpQuestionWithDefault() {
    /*These two variables store a local copy of packedQuestion. These variables are first updated with the information from
    onChange (or a variation of it), and then packedQuestion is set to an instance of this. */
    const local_question_mcq = { // <-- provide initial values, then override
      id: props.id,
      title: `Question ${props.id}`,
    };
    const local_answerChoices_mcq = {};

    function addOption(character, value = '') {
      local_answerChoices_mcq[character] = value;
      local_question_mcq["answer_choices"] = local_answerChoices_mcq;
    }

    function addQuestion(title, value) {
      local_question_mcq[title ? "title" : "question_text"] = value; // <-- DRY
    }

    addQuestion(true, "Question " + props.id);
    addQuestion(false, "");

    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].forEach(c => addOption(c, '')); // <-- DRY

    setPackedQuestion(local_question_mcq);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fillUpQuestionWithDefault();
  }, []);

  function optionOnInputFunc(character, value) {
    setPackedQuestion((question) => ({ // <-- functional state update
      ...question,
      answer_choices: {
        ...question.answer_choices,
        [character]: value
      }
    }));
  }

  function questionOnInputFunc(title, value) {
    setPackedQuestion((question) => ({ // <-- functional state update
      ...question,
      [title ? 'title' : 'question_text']: value
    }));
  }

  function mcqChoiceGeneratingFunc() {
    return (
      <div className="Opt">
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Paper className="Question">
      ...
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nested-object-stored-as-state-variable-deleting-newer-values-when-older-values-a]

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling this function from child component then ques take the value of initial state in hook that is {}. Now you are adding key quesID in temp and updating the state. So it will be an expected behavior.

```
function returnFromMcqQuestion(prevQues, quesID, thisQuestion) {
            var temp = {...prevQues};
            temp["ques"+quesID] = thisQuestion;
    
            setQues(prevQues);
          }
```

So you need something like this.

```
<McqQuestion ques={ques} returnfunc={returnFromMcqQuestion} id={questionid}/>)
useEffect(()=> props.returnfunc(props.ques, props.id, packedQuestion));
```